# Как получить путь к изображению?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить путь к изображению, когда блоки находятся на одном уровне, таких блоков несколько, просто обратится по классу не правильно, как можно это реализовать?
Мой код ищет путь у родителя, как можно исправить?

```
        <div class="select-organaiser__item">
            <div class="item-img img-stand">
                <img src="img/stand-3.png" alt="organaiser">
            </div>
            <div class="item-title">
                <h3>Комплект брелков для гаджетов </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="item-old-price">
                558 
            </div>
            <div class="item-price">
                279 
            </div>
            <div class="item-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <a class="buyprod" onclick="i=6;pr=279;">Заказать</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(".buyprod").click(function () {
        var img = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
        var text = $(this).parent().find(".name").text();
        var price = $(this).parent().find(".price").text();
        if($('.item'+i).length) {
          document.getElementById('input'+i).value = parseInt(document.getElementById('input'+i).value,10)+1;
          $(".price"+i).html('' + (parseInt(document.getElementById('input' + i).value, 10) * pr));
        }
        else{
           $("#cartdiv").append(`
          <div id="cart_item" class="item${i}">
          <div class="remove" data-delete=${i}>X</div>
          <div>${text}</div>
          <img src="${img}" alt="photo1"><br>
          <div class="minus" data-index=${i}>-</div>
          <input type="test" id="input${i}" value="1" readonly="true"/>
          <div class="plus" data-index=${i}>+</div>
          <div class="price${i}">${price}</div>
          </div>
          `);
          }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил это так, может кому-то будет полезно:

```
var img = $(this).prevAll(".item-img").find("img").attr("src");
```